# How to find the operand of a sinusoid?

Tags: functions

For a function $\sin[2x]$, the operand is $2x$. If we want know the value of the operand by hand, the function is simply $\arcsin(\sin[2x])=2x$. How to do this with Mathematica?

Here's what I tried:

```
ArcSin[Sin[2 x]]
```

Which, if you try it, does not provide any information.

Comment: Do you *need* to apply `ArcSin`, or could you just try `First@Sin[2 x]`; the latter will return the argument of `Sin` *mechanically* (for lack of a better word), rather than through calculation.

Comment: @MarcoB I get the error `Syntax::sntxf: "First@" cannot be followed by "[Sin[2*x]]".`

Comment: I just want the 2x back. I think Mathematica has an easy way that I don't know.

Comment: `# & @@ Sin[2 x]`?

Comment: @axsvl77 Works fine for me, if you follow the example exactly. It's either `First@Sin[2 x]` or `First[Sin[2 x]]` but not both `@` and `[ ... ]` (`@` is really single-argument special form of `[ ... ]`.)

Comment: @kirma That work for me too. Will you put it as answer?

Comment: This mechanism is pretty fiddly, though, because whatever you pass to `First` might be evaluated to a different form before `First` starts extraction of the first argument. For instance, `First@Sin[1]` works while `First@Sin[0]` doesn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps what you are looking for is:

```
# & @@ Sin[2 x]
```

> 2 x

When the argument is a list and some elements of it have a numerical value we need to use [`Unevaluated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html) to prevent evaluation of `Sin`:

```
# & @@ Unevaluated @ Sin[{2 x, π, 3., y}]
```

> {2 x, π, 3., y}